# How can India keep a balance of relationship with both Russia and the USA after signing 4 pacts with the USA?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, india

Historically India has very good relationships with USSR/Russia. India uses a lot of Soviet/Russian weapons, aircraft, ships, and sub-systems.

In recent years, India decided to shed its non-aligned posture and decided to move toward the American pole. From 2002 to 2018, India signed GSOMIA, LEMOA, COMCASA. BECA is under process as of March-2020.

1. GSOMIA = India has to ensure the secrecy of American technology
2. LEMOA = India and the USA can share each other's military establishments
3. COMCASA = India will be able to use American military encryption tech
4. BECA = India will have to ensure information security and share geographical data for both civilian and military use

How can India keep a balance of relationship with both Russia and the USA after signing 4 pacts with the USA?

Comment: **US did tell India not to buy S-400**, and offered THAAD, if India cancels S-400. However, didn't hesitate in selling weapons (can't remember the names, it includes some helicopters, torpedoes, etc). But in case of Turkey, US cancelled the selling of F-35 citing "technical" reasons like "those two can't be together".

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in [a piece](https://foreignpolicy.com/2020/07/08/russia-india-relations/) in *Foreign Policy*, yes, a more balanced geo-political stance is possible because the world has changed since the Cold War.

> The “best” and “most substantive” relationship that India has is with the United States, said C. Raja Mohan, the director of the Institute of South Asian Studies at the National University of Singapore. India “is not going to sacrifice that to say, ‘I was once married to the Russians.’” Certainly, that U.S. President Donald Trump’s secretaries of state, Rex Tillerson and Mike Pompeo, both gave major speeches about India and the Indo-Pacific early on in their tenures suggests that **India is important to the United States**; that Trump went to India in February of this year on a visit that was heavy on ceremony (if light on substance) suggests the same.
>
> But **being friendly with Washington does not mean New Delhi can’t maintain important ties with Moscow**. The world has changed, but India and Russia have found ways for their relationship to hold firm, standing steady for each other at times when the rest of the world wouldn’t, maintaining largely consistent foreign policies despite changing leaderships, and refusing to bury a historic partnership.

As the "India–Russia relations" [on Wikpedia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/56107/can-india-keep-a-balance-of-relationship-with-both-russia-and-the-usa-after-sign) mentions, India has also signed a major defense deal with Russia as recently as 2018. Only if tensions between the US and Russia worsen considerably would I expect that India may be forced to choose sides.

EDIT: [Here](https://www.businessinsider.com/arms-sales-by-the-us-and-russia-2014-8) is a piece on *Business Insider* showing that India was one of 15 countries which purchased arms from both the US and Russia in 2013.

[image: table of 2013 arms purchases]

Comment: How can the USA trust India ensuring the secrecy of American tech and data?

Comment: I'm not finding any handy references on this but my understanding is that the US and Russia sell arms to many of the same countries, and that the US imposes various protocols that are meant to prevent unauthorized technology transfers. For example, if India allowed a Russian technician to access a certain jet, this would be a major violation of the agreement. Russia may impose similar restrictions on the technology it sells as well.

Comment: @user366312 Also see my edit above.

Comment: @user366312 I don't think it is; you may just need to dismiss the notification. But in any cases, I added an image.

Comment: The link doesn't work from my end no matter it is behind paywall or not.

Comment: The Russian made weapon systems are not worth much without spare parts also produced in Russia. So there is no way India can break all ties with Russia. I hope the USA understood that when the treaties were negotiated.